# percentage letters don't show up on bottom of screen

Tags: just-cause-2

My percentage doesn't show up at the bottom of the screen. it's currently 19% and the flaming "19.xx%" numbers don't show up. I've only completed 6 agency missions, keep that in mind. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Little late to the party, but it seems that it only shows you the percentage in all flaming awesomeness after you've entered Mercenary Mode. One enters Mercenary Mode after the last Agency Mission.

Meanwhile, you can check the percentage from your PDA, but I guess you already found that out, cause you knew your percentage.